# Site Admin. Why are some settings updated on "Save" while others "OnChange"

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, stack-overflow-for-teams, user-interface, user-experience

When I want to upload or *change profile* information it requires me to click Save which is fine.  When I change one of my users to an Admin, it saves it after I select it.  Seem inconsistent and in this case I would suggest having it be one way, but not feature specific.

Comment: This is a feature request that falls under the heading of "Is this important enough to get attention right now (or ever), given other, possibly more pressing things that also need to be done?"

Comment: Related: [Profile picture upload, then disappear](/q/305307/4642212). I think I’ve seen one or maybe two more questions about this. It doesn’t seem that a lot of users are _struggling_ with this, but I agree that this should eventually be made consistent. Note that the profile is currently in the [process of being redesigned](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/368285/289905) anyway and that the profile picture uploader is [old and buggy anyway](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/353729/289905), so maybe this will be fixed eventually.

Comment: I also noticed the issue with the picture, which led me to the Save button vs auto save on change question.

Comment: I guess the "problem" with editing the profile is that you actually have 2 choices: [1) apply on this site only, or 2) apply network-wide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kr8je.png) (not sure if the user only has 1 community), while other settings are trivial.